# SSIS - OLE Db destination connection error in for each loop

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I have dataflow task in a for each loop in a SSIS package. It dumps data into a ole db destination which is a Sql Server database. It works successfully for about nine iterations in the for-each loop, and then errors out on the tenth:

```
Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.

The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager xxxxx failed with error code 0xC0202009.

TCP Only one usage of each socket address protocol/network address/port is normally permitted.
```

Just to clarify , I am not changing any connections dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the RetainSameConnection property on the Connection Manager from false to true. You can find this property by right-clicking the connection manager and then clicking Properties.